# How can I prettyprint a JSON Dataframe in spark with Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe from that I want to write to a json file as valid json:

My current code looks like:

```
val df: DataFrame = myFun(...)
df.toJSON.saveAsTextFile( "myFile.json" )
```

The format of the output is:

```
{}{}{}
```

How can I get the file contents to organize as valid JSON?:

```
[{},{},{}]
```

Comment: still looking.  `toJSON` and `write.json(` both can only put complete json objects on each line so you end up with a linefeed delimited file of individual json objects instead of a valid json file, ie: an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround using Spray JSON:

```
def apply(df: DataFrame): Option[String] = {
    val collectedData  = df.toJSON.coalesce(1).collect().mkString("\n")
    val json = "[" + ("}\n".r replaceAllIn (collectedData, "},\n")) + "]"
    val pretty = json.parseJson.prettyPrint
    Some(s"$pretty\n")
}
```

ugly and inefficient but does what I want provided the final result isn't big-data huge, in which case I wouldn't want a single proper json file anyway.

Comment: `parseJson` is not a member of string, are you using some framework ?

Comment: @GauravShah, yes, the Spray JSON libs

Answer (score 0):

I am using this ( Python )

```
import json
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dumps
with open('myJson.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(myDF, outfile)
```

I am sure you will find an alternative with `Scala`.