# Can I save a Dataframe as pretty format JSON in Spark Scala?

Tags: json, scala, csv, apache-spark

While reading a CSV file as Dataframe in Spark Scala, can we save the file as pretty format JSON with the root tags?

Comment: Look at the solution provided here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37175140/how-can-i-prettyprint-a-json-dataframe-in-spark-with-scala

Answer (score 0):

I have following df:

```
+------+-----+
|number| word|
+------+-----+
|     8|  bat|
|    64|mouse|
|   -27|horse|
+------+-----+
```

If you want to create a root element you can use the following approach:
1. Create a function which will convert you DF to DF with JSON column:

```
def convertDFToJSON(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val columns = df.columns
    val outDF = df.map(row =>
      "myroot : " +
      JSONObject(row.getValuesMap(columns)).toString()
    )
    outDF.toDF("bla")
}
```

2. Apply a function on your DF:

```
val test1 = convertDFToJSON(someDF)
+--------------------+
|                 bla|
+--------------------+
|myroot : {"number...|
|myroot : {"number...|
|myroot : {"number...|
+--------------------+
```

3. Write a DF as a text:

```
test1.write.text("/tmp/some")
```

output:

```
myroot : {"number" : 8, "word" : "bat"}
myroot : {"number" : 64, "word" : "mouse"}
myroot : {"number" : -27, "word" : "horse"}
```

Comment: import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject